# How to translation from MathCAD to Python. Or how Find and rkfixed works?

Tags: python, math, mathcad

I can't translate a formula from Mathcad to Python. Stuck on the Find and rkfixed functions. Don't even know how functions Find and rkfixed works. If I would know I don't ask how to translate them. Of course you can tell me universal solution which tells how Find and rkfixed functions works not even for python. I would happy for any kind of your help.

T1, T2 are the initial approximations.

The first formula with Find()

[image]

T is the initial approximation.

The second formula with rkfixed()

[image]

Comment: Looks like algebra to get a 2x2 matrix equation is all that is required.  You should be able to do that without worrying about Mathcad or Python.  Once you have that, any language or system that can solve a 2x2 system of equations should be able to do it.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Sympy (https://sympy.org), especially in combination with Jupyter (https://jupyter.org). Good luck and have fun.